# how to pass a function down to child component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a newbie Vue question about how to pass a function down to a grandchild components. Vuex is overkill in this situation and emit event doesn't look nice than Function passing in syntax.

GrandParent component:

```
 <b-tabs card v-model="tabIndex" active-nav-item-class="nav-active">
          <b-tab title="Tổng quan">
            <LazyDataLeagueGeneral
              @changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"                 
            />
           
          </b-tab>
          <b-tab title="Lịch thi đấu"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
          <b-tab title="Thống kê cầu thủ"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

has method

```
changeLoadingBar(status) {
      this.loadingBar = status;
      console.log(status);
    },
```

On General component, it has another child component call TeamStandings and pass the changeLoadingBar again

```
<LazyDataLeagueTeamStandings
        :changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"           
      />

props: {
    changeLoadingBar: Function
}
```

TeamStandings (grandchild):

```
props: {
        changeLoadingBar: Function
    }
```

I try to make a call to changeLoadingBar but get **TypeError: this.changeLoadingBar is not a function**

```
mounted() {
    console.log("progress mounted");
    this.changeLoadingBar(false);
  },
```

**UPDATED: at grandparent I forgot to pass prop to child**

```
<LazyDataLeagueGeneral
                  @changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"    
                  :changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"             
                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: at grandparent I forgot to pass prop to child

```
<LazyDataLeagueGeneral
                  @changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"    
                  :changeLoadingBar="changeLoadingBar"             
                />
```

call changeLoadingBar directly from a grandChild:  **this.changeLoadingBar(false);**

another way is to just use Provide/inject (will make **indirect** call to changeLoadingbar function)

Grandparent component:

```
provide() {
    return {
      callChangeLoadingBar: this.changeLoadingBar,
    };
  },
```

on grandchild component TeamStanding:

```
inject:[
    'callChangeLoadingBar'
  ],
```

and just call indirectly changeLoadingBar: **this.callChangeLoadingBar(false)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
props: {
    changeLoadingBar: {
      type: Function,
      required: true, //true or false
      default: () => { this.myMethod() },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      alert("I'm Ok!");
    }
  }
```

Comment: that method is on the grandparent component. I want to have a grandchild to call grandparent method because loadingBar lies on the grandparent.

Comment: pass data  twice with emitting your grandchild data to grandparent

Comment: thanks, but emit event syntax on deeply nested components does not look nice. I've found 2 ways in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Passing down function props like this can quickly become very messy, especially with multiple n level child/grandchild/... components. In your example the Child component basically just proxies the function to the grandchild, all that is just redundant code.

This use case is typically ideal for a store (Vuex) or something like the eventHub pattern. Since you discarded Vuex as being overkill, then I would highly recommend to look into the eventHub pattern. In Vue 2 you can implement this pattern directly, or from Vue 3 it is [recommended](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#_3-x-update) to use a 3rd party library like [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt). These libraries are tiny e.g. mitt is literally 200 bytes gzipped.

With this pattern your example case is trivial to implement and arguably much cleaner.